# Negative sign in rotation operator (quantum mechanics, angular momentum)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, conventions

Schaum's Quantum Mechanics comes up with

$$\exp((-i/\hbar)\cdot \theta \cdot{\hat{L}} \cdot {\overrightarrow{n}})$$

as the formula of the rotation operator.   Other sources I see don't
have the negative sign.  How did they get the negative sign in here?

Comment: The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_operator_%28quantum_mechanics%29) page, gives the sign alright. what sources are you talking about?

Comment: This is one but thanks for pointing out that the Wikipedia one does give the negative sign.  I had overlooked that somehow.

Comment: Could you explain the Wikipedia derivation please?  Specifically, I don't understand their step after  "Taylor development gives".  I understand Taylor series but the application is confusing here, especially with the parentheses notations.

Comment: Also, that Wikipedia article says ${p_x} = i \hbar  (dT(0)/da)$, but shouldn't it be ${p_x} = -i \hbar  (dT(0)/da)$?

Comment: Oops, above I meant to say this page is one source that does not have the negative sign.  http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node275.html

Comment: When I stare at that wikipedia page / proof, a voice in my head keeps saying  Ta da!..  Ta da!..

Comment: This page http://www.physicspages.com/2013/01/30/angular-momentum-as-a-generator-of-rotations/ has it without the negative sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both negative sign and positive sign are correct. When you make an infinitesimal rotation with angle $d\phi$ about the z-axis, then both two following representations for transformed coordinates are true:
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
x'=x-d\phi y \\
y'=y+d\phi x \end{array} \right.
$$
and
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
x'=x+d\phi y \\
y'=y-d\phi x \end{array} \right.
$$
The former leads to the positive sign, while the later leads to the negative sign.

Comment: I thought there was only one way to rotate about the z axis, by the right hand rule.  Thank you for your statement though, which I'm sure is true.

Comment: This page is helping me understand why it's okay to take only a first order approximation here  ($x - d\phi * y$ and y + $d\phi * x$).  https://reedbeta.wordpress.com/2011/09/18/rotations-and-infinitesimal-generators/

Comment: Another way I think about it is:   You know that when you want to create an operator that would translate a wave function by $\Delta x$ in the positive x direction, you make a new wave function that returns the value of the old wave function, at every point $x_0$, the value $\psi(x_0 - \Delta x)$.  i.e. if $\Delta x$ is positive, then by having the minus sign there, you actually end up shifting the wave function TO THE RIGHT  (as desired, since $\Delta x$ is positive).  What this ends up meaning is that when you write the translation operator it ends up

Comment: being $e^{-(i/\hbar) (\Delta x) (d/dx)}$ with the minus sign.  It seems to be similar behavior for creating the Rotation operator.  If you just have $e^{+(i/\hbar) (\Delta \phi)(d/d\phi)}$ naively, you end up rotating your wave function in the WRONG  (opposite from desired)  direction.

Comment: Thanks to march's comment on the other question  "Negative sign in rotation operator again"  that led to this interpretation.